# Using ConnectionString name in parameter

Tags: c#, autofac

I currently have an autofac section in my web.config that looks like this.

```xml
<autofac>
  <components>
    <component type="MilepointLog.Repositories.Repository, MilepointLog.Repositories" 
               service="MilepointLog.Repositories.IITDMilepointRepository, MilepointLog.Repositories">
      <parameters>
        <parameter name="connectionString" value="test" />
      </parameters>
    </component>
  </components>
</autofac>
```

What I need to do is using the connection string I have above this code as the value. The `connectionStringName` is called *MilePointLog*.

Here is the section in my *Global.Asax* that has the other autofac code.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));

builder.RegisterType<Service>()
       .As<IITDMilePointService>().InstancePerRequest();
//builder.RegisterType<Repository>()
//       .As<IITDMilepointRepository>()
//       .WithParameter("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MilePointLog"].ConnectionString);
builder.RegisterType<HomeController>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so can you tell me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Autofac* doesn't support what you want out of the box.

The solution I would recommend is to change the implementation of your `Repository` to accept a named connectionstring.

```
public class Repository 
{
    public Repository(String connectionStringName)
    {
        String connectionString = 
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for.  I'll take your recommended route.  Thank you for your time.